# ES6 using static method to create new instance gives undefined for child class attributes

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I have the following child class:

```
export default class File extends Model {
  selected = false
}
```

And the parent class:

```
export default class Model {
  constructor (attributes = {}) {
    if (new.target === Model) {
      throw Error('Not allowed to instantiate Model')
    }

    Object.assign(this, attributes)
  }

  static build (attributes) {
    return new this(attributes)
  }
}
```

I expected that when using

```
const file = File.build({selected: true})
```

the result for file.selected would have been true, but remains false. Logging "this" inside the constructor, I can see the File instance doesn't have the selected attribute at all, returning undefined.

Using the current babel config

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          node: 'current'
        }
      },
      '@babel/preset-typescript'
    ]
  ],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-transform-typescript',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'
  ]
}
```

If I do not define selected on the child class, the result will then be true for file.selected

Comment: Try defining a constructor in File class and call parent constructor passing arguments to it

Comment: Tried constructor(props){super(props)} in File, but test still shows selected to be false

Comment: Can you put return statement as `return Object.assign()` along with it

Comment: Tried return Object.assign(this, attributes) inside the constructor of Model, tried also constructor(props){ return super(props) }, still negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you move the `Object.assign` to the `build` method instead of the constructor?

Example:

```js
class Model {
  constructor () {
    if (new.target === Model) {
      throw Error('Not allowed to instantiate Model')
    }
  }

  static build (attributes) {
    const obj = new this(attributes)
    Object.assign(obj, attributes)
    return obj
  }
}

class File extends Model {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.selected = false
    this.defaultValue = 'default'
  }
}

const file = File.build({selected: true, foo: 'bar'})

console.log(file);
```

Comment: Thanks, moving Object.assign into build did it for me. Even though I wish I could keep the ability ````const instance = new this(); Object.assign(instance, attributes); return instance;```` Only sad that I can't use new File({selected: true}), but I can't picture a situation where I would have to.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields:

> Public instance fields are added with `Object.defineProperty` either at construction time in the base class (before the constructor body runs), **or just after `super()` returns in a subclass.**

`this.selected` doesn’t get set in time for the parent constructor to see it (which matches when you’re allowed to use `this` inside a constructor). One alternative could be to put the initial value on the prototype instead:

```
File.prototype.selected = false;
```

Comment: Thanks, this was informative and confirmed that it's not a bug.